# Generally speaking, what is a Domain folder? What does it mean/contain?

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, frameworks

Lately I have been looking at a lot of different php frameworks and various php packages. Whenever I first look at project, like said frameworks or packages, I try to digest it's directory structure to get a clue as to its organization. I've noticed that there are often reoccuring themes, like an "app" folder, a "tests" folder, a "src" folder, a "var" folder and so on and so forth. Usually I understand what these folders represent or mean, however lately I have been coming across a folder I do not understand in project directories: a "Domain" folder.

What does a Domain folder represent? What kinds of logic or code are contained therein? Does it have any relation to an actual Domain name?

Any and all input would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
To provide a specific example of what finally prompted me to ask this question, I was looking at the starter boilerplate that is generated by the php "slim" framework. You can generate this project by using php's tool composer and running:

```
composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton [app-folder]
```

Here is [a link](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) to the repo on github. Within the "src" folder of this project, there is a "Domain" folder. At least for this specific example, what does the Domain folder represent?

Comment: And what is there in this folder?

Comment: This is impossible to answer. It can mean all kinds of things depending on what the developer(s) wanted it to mean. I could name a folder `cat` refering to objects used for concatenation, but I might as well meant an image of my pet.

Comment: https://stitcher.io/blog/organise-by-domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Domain" is the main term in DDD (Domain Driven Design) architecture. it has many concepts to learn but in summary, we can say that the Domain section is the core section of your application logic and it contains your domain models and their services like factories and model validations. I suggest you read this reference, it can help you to comprehend DDD concepts.

https://martinfowler.com/tags/domain%20driven%20design.html

Edit: 
In your example which you mentioned, as you see there is a "User" model in the domain section that there are some of their services like exceptions or interfaces of its repository.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just a point in the right direction. Searching "domain folder" and whatnot got me nowhere on google.

Comment: You're most welcome, searching "domain" is more correct than "domain folder" because the domain is a concept, not just a folder. As I said it's better that you read the Martin Fowler articles about DDD. @robitwtms